# Can't figure XOR encryption

Tags: xor

I'm doing a CTF challenge and I got the text file with the flag but it's encrypted in XOR.
I've been looking everywhere trying to find how to decrypt it and I just can't figure it out.

0x3bc10x3cca0x26d40x12d80x2e50x3cdb0x18f20x1a9d0x29f20x149a0x7cd0
and i belive this is a key = 5DAD

I tried to remove the 0x and decrypt it in python scripts I found but nothing works.
What am I missing?

Comment: By "remove the 0x" you mean you converted the values or you actually just removed 0x from that string?

Comment: I just removed 0x from the string

Comment: Most likely that 0x was indicating the following is an hex value, which means you must NOT just remove 0x. You must convert the hex value to a character. THEN you decrypt.